# Need help parsing manga images using BeautifulSoup/requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, urllib

I am beginner in Python and I have learned most of the basics of the program. So I decided to create my first project in order to test my skills and understanding. My project involves parsing images for a certain manga chapter from a website called https://bato.to/. Upon looking at the html code, I notice the image code is hidden and is put in a format I never seen before.

```
</script>

<script>
var seriesId = 69462;
var chapterId = 1204541;
var images = {"1":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/57a04a3ce55bd48debf0a486a4c1a48f6380ef9b_1066291_800_1138.png","2":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/a0f75d10919430e6ef25a86c3dcc65f343d8e319_518773_800_1138.png","3":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/575d00ff9ef6873ee9ecfb418e360fe72cc1c594_418309_800_1138.png","4":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/cf839d2425379267218aa666d655e78bd0ee4e4a_425299_800_1138.png","5":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/99e371b684dafca9a91b0a7ad447f51582640bfa_480515_800_1138.png","6":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/7780852155c02e4e6b5059beb97131788274c561_614212_800_1138.png","7":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/569b810f952dd3146c7f120d23b24ee7c9707486_548081_800_1138.png","8":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/53d251f743b61863d6d7557844b34ff5152e1609_484778_800_1138.png","9":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/7800fbe47802269e499b2f70fe53b41a52b0594b_410873_800_1138.png","10":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/3583ca41d7ff56641fae4a717e9b612c1ac365f2_436785_800_1138.png","11":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/81eac44fa63bdbdf2e0d29163ff56d79bc71c820_389040_800_1138.png","12":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/b2a0b8833f0002679a06e20f96bcb205306cf903_678271_800_1138.png","13":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/6873e24ba5f0f81b3b86197f99505f4ea04f2ed6_502645_800_1138.png","14":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/6f230cdb1078942871f201f46a7375fdb80c7725_491192_800_1138.png","15":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/b7300babacb6c266c4b01f69cce5178723cacab1_569510_800_1138.png","16":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/5b098d44ddf7e5c859622ca3a0a4b3b73207bf27_617792_800_1138.png","17":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/9acd39d7658b4a1a85b8873d4aa90161d1f43f89_400216_800_1138.png","18":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4e8465f5b2d5051412ccea9dd3b516d37d2f7e78_505009_800_1138.png","19":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/074944985caaa096dc99cf560244ed4f88e7c134_447556_800_1138.png","20":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4e1207273bd67333ab2c498327255725378bff5a_744103_800_1138.png","21":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/b5a3c3ba757be5aaa5bbc5d0c3f563fbb45391f3_444943_800_1138.png","22":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/cb146368fddf4fe9bc80088a5bd5784dd49dfc5a_561421_800_1138.png","23":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/c929cac013ee5b3794600c925850263f54a17a39_488726_800_1138.png","24":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4b8d797546fc185eedcb7efbad5e1e50a4f565cc_479310_800_1138.png","25":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/39c1028bc26adb25171e79b8c739422b8d7c6780_492937_800_1138.png","26":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/e27a386a1f7e95fade1822e5f71dc23797289f08_1069178_1600_1138.png","27":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/51ad85180a93eeb24ea42182c70a45431a483739_504148_800_1138.png","28":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/90b431bfadfe3afd2efa0ab661a1dcda10e309e3_343208_800_1138.png","29":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/48ae08934d842797654822c5535ae7bb132b2643_444143_800_1138.png","30":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/411a7e9fce98275133915a1bfffa4a402dee7b8e_343839_800_1138.png","31":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/614e2cb8de3836b276eb22cdae62ca4c7c6157dd_601185_800_1138.png","32":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/674d038df3e5c9a472a11451ba262eaed67e7390_535795_800_1138.png","33":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d33951612052b7a452e6973b6a2cb5d74210fe05_447169_800_1138.png","34":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/0a6c377f3960ef407ad9ea5c6f46409eb172327c_342094_800_1138.png","35":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d7bfffc6e37d14f4cdd9a6f085355427cd86c3e9_414864_800_1138.png","36":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/87e86923d96455e89e8e3138b3ab5992df17cc79_541358_800_1138.png","37":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/f1c2fe8001425d88e9700633a7891f0901872f55_135829_800_1138.png","38":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/7cd38bb71e091a66c75c2b8a8d05822571c1428b_560422_800_1138.png","39":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/8f6c69eeba0f1f153153d789985dae5b20ee384f_691293_800_1138.png","40":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/ad062d6080615fb08ae2e0d2f8ed092cc3223620_602280_800_1138.png","41":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/5be961c28583bb1dd92725c7c105a4bcf529cef6_484232_800_1138.png","42":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4fdd26894c2a900d4c0cc3ddcf340973419a93a6_533468_800_1138.png","43":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/0ca26c4e3d2d26be25b9bca9b50302ccf1117f80_579802_800_1138.png","44":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/08ce8bbe30f835caa898e6e148e49e1c9b590a8d_603324_800_1138.png","45":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/6dc238a9f03d20f7070d83fd2b2b6d677517c5cf_435471_800_1138.png","46":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/5cd269da6e198133f5da5e9bb125492366df9469_597385_800_1138.png","47":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/c916e3cdeccecfa1cf5b9ae70bdc11a3b20c678f_661926_800_1138.png","48":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/dcc84a86d5379c830f0c0087339cb685ca757999_547146_800_1138.png","49":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/de9b88d1ccfc9acf6a437fff49bf73a535af6370_886149_1600_1138.png","50":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/aa41d6836befb0ae8755c767a892cbfc065223f7_1307106_1600_1138.png","51":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d0320e80cdac4a4e9ac84f920b9b53fb30029b20_478527_800_1138.png","52":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d3c65f840473c8f14de55fda2581e0fa24433410_563860_800_1138.png","53":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/373a7b778e7d335d6d75f611c43559286b3905a0_523659_800_1138.png","54":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/ef7215fe9b2dc00607518a8b14d92e8848ba71b0_507280_800_1138.png","55":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4642779f14b16771af87b63229f15bae9006f4a3_459041_800_1138.png","56":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/db2065e24505b2b3ef633917cca106864aa22baf_436436_800_1138.png","57":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/459f0c4f5359ac0ee516c2175a25ca3c25276cbd_517997_800_1138.png","58":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d489e9dfe04de6f8f5c377b513da55d6a15b59dd_443413_800_1138.png","59":"https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/32b5347b7bd423ab8004c3ef1e5336bc8b13ea3a_368964_800_1138.png"};
var pages = 59;
var page = 0;
var prevCha = {"base":{"uniqueId":1200264,"parentId":0,"seriesId":69462,"createDate":"2018-04-10T06:08:16.041Z","publicDate":"2018-04-10T06:08:16.041Z","modifyDate":null,"updateDate":"2018-04-10T06:08:16.041Z","sortHash":"zzzzz.zzzzz.00090.00000"},"_extra":{"volcha":"Ch.90","updateDateAgo":"22 days ago","updateDateDif":22}};
var nextCha = null;
</script>
```

I tried using BeautifulSoup to find the `var images` tag to extract the directory with image links but I was not able to get it. I have never worked with "var" tags. 
Can someone tell me how to extract `var images` tag?
This is code I have written so far, but I am stuck. I cant figure out how to extract the tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import os
import re

os.makedirs('OnePunch',exist_ok = True)
# Download the page
url = 'https://bato.to/chapter/1204541.com'
source = requests.get(url).text

print(source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import os
import re

# Download the page
url = 'https://bato.to/chapter/1204541.com'
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
scr = soup.find_all("script")
pattern = re.compile(r"var\s+images\s+=(.*)")     #Regex to get the script with var images

for i in scr:
    m = pattern.search(i.text)
    if m:
        print(json.loads(m.group(1).replace(";", "")))
```

**Output:**

```
{u'56': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/db2065e24505b2b3ef633917cca106864aa22baf_436436_800_1138.png', u'54': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/ef7215fe9b2dc00607518a8b14d92e8848ba71b0_507280_800_1138.png', u'42': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4fdd26894c2a900d4c0cc3ddcf340973419a93a6_533468_800_1138.png', u'48': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/dcc84a86d5379c830f0c0087339cb685ca757999_547146_800_1138.png', u'43': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/0ca26c4e3d2d26be25b9bca9b50302ccf1117f80_579802_800_1138.png', u'49': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/de9b88d1ccfc9acf6a437fff49bf73a535af6370_886149_1600_1138.png', u'52': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d3c65f840473c8f14de55fda2581e0fa24433410_563860_800_1138.png', u'53': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/373a7b778e7d335d6d75f611c43559286b3905a0_523659_800_1138.png', u'24': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4b8d797546fc185eedcb7efbad5e1e50a4f565cc_479310_800_1138.png', u'25': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/39c1028bc26adb25171e79b8c739422b8d7c6780_492937_800_1138.png', u'26': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/e27a386a1f7e95fade1822e5f71dc23797289f08_1069178_1600_1138.png', u'27': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/51ad85180a93eeb24ea42182c70a45431a483739_504148_800_1138.png', u'20': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4e1207273bd67333ab2c498327255725378bff5a_744103_800_1138.png', u'21': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/b5a3c3ba757be5aaa5bbc5d0c3f563fbb45391f3_444943_800_1138.png', u'22': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/cb146368fddf4fe9bc80088a5bd5784dd49dfc5a_561421_800_1138.png', u'23': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/c929cac013ee5b3794600c925850263f54a17a39_488726_800_1138.png', u'46': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/5cd269da6e198133f5da5e9bb125492366df9469_597385_800_1138.png', u'47': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/c916e3cdeccecfa1cf5b9ae70bdc11a3b20c678f_661926_800_1138.png', u'44': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/08ce8bbe30f835caa898e6e148e49e1c9b590a8d_603324_800_1138.png', u'45': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/6dc238a9f03d20f7070d83fd2b2b6d677517c5cf_435471_800_1138.png', u'28': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/90b431bfadfe3afd2efa0ab661a1dcda10e309e3_343208_800_1138.png', u'29': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/48ae08934d842797654822c5535ae7bb132b2643_444143_800_1138.png', u'40': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/ad062d6080615fb08ae2e0d2f8ed092cc3223620_602280_800_1138.png', u'41': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/5be961c28583bb1dd92725c7c105a4bcf529cef6_484232_800_1138.png', u'1': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/57a04a3ce55bd48debf0a486a4c1a48f6380ef9b_1066291_800_1138.png', u'3': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/575d00ff9ef6873ee9ecfb418e360fe72cc1c594_418309_800_1138.png', u'2': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/a0f75d10919430e6ef25a86c3dcc65f343d8e319_518773_800_1138.png', u'5': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/99e371b684dafca9a91b0a7ad447f51582640bfa_480515_800_1138.png', u'4': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/cf839d2425379267218aa666d655e78bd0ee4e4a_425299_800_1138.png', u'7': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/569b810f952dd3146c7f120d23b24ee7c9707486_548081_800_1138.png', u'6': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/7780852155c02e4e6b5059beb97131788274c561_614212_800_1138.png', u'9': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/7800fbe47802269e499b2f70fe53b41a52b0594b_410873_800_1138.png', u'8': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/53d251f743b61863d6d7557844b34ff5152e1609_484778_800_1138.png', u'51': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d0320e80cdac4a4e9ac84f920b9b53fb30029b20_478527_800_1138.png', u'39': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/8f6c69eeba0f1f153153d789985dae5b20ee384f_691293_800_1138.png', u'38': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/7cd38bb71e091a66c75c2b8a8d05822571c1428b_560422_800_1138.png', u'59': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/32b5347b7bd423ab8004c3ef1e5336bc8b13ea3a_368964_800_1138.png', u'58': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d489e9dfe04de6f8f5c377b513da55d6a15b59dd_443413_800_1138.png', u'11': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/81eac44fa63bdbdf2e0d29163ff56d79bc71c820_389040_800_1138.png', u'10': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/3583ca41d7ff56641fae4a717e9b612c1ac365f2_436785_800_1138.png', u'13': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/6873e24ba5f0f81b3b86197f99505f4ea04f2ed6_502645_800_1138.png', u'12': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/b2a0b8833f0002679a06e20f96bcb205306cf903_678271_800_1138.png', u'15': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/b7300babacb6c266c4b01f69cce5178723cacab1_569510_800_1138.png', u'14': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/6f230cdb1078942871f201f46a7375fdb80c7725_491192_800_1138.png', u'17': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/9acd39d7658b4a1a85b8873d4aa90161d1f43f89_400216_800_1138.png', u'16': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/5b098d44ddf7e5c859622ca3a0a4b3b73207bf27_617792_800_1138.png', u'19': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/074944985caaa096dc99cf560244ed4f88e7c134_447556_800_1138.png', u'18': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4e8465f5b2d5051412ccea9dd3b516d37d2f7e78_505009_800_1138.png', u'31': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/614e2cb8de3836b276eb22cdae62ca4c7c6157dd_601185_800_1138.png', u'30': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/411a7e9fce98275133915a1bfffa4a402dee7b8e_343839_800_1138.png', u'37': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/f1c2fe8001425d88e9700633a7891f0901872f55_135829_800_1138.png', u'36': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/87e86923d96455e89e8e3138b3ab5992df17cc79_541358_800_1138.png', u'35': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d7bfffc6e37d14f4cdd9a6f085355427cd86c3e9_414864_800_1138.png', u'34': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/0a6c377f3960ef407ad9ea5c6f46409eb172327c_342094_800_1138.png', u'33': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/d33951612052b7a452e6973b6a2cb5d74210fe05_447169_800_1138.png', u'55': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/4642779f14b16771af87b63229f15bae9006f4a3_459041_800_1138.png', u'32': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/674d038df3e5c9a472a11451ba262eaed67e7390_535795_800_1138.png', u'57': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/459f0c4f5359ac0ee516c2175a25ca3c25276cbd_517997_800_1138.png', u'50': u'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/aa41d6836befb0ae8755c767a892cbfc065223f7_1307106_1600_1138.png'}
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much for the help. You given me a huge hint regarding regular expressions. I was told never to use regular expressions on html pages. Never knew there was an exception.

Comment: @BluHaz You should avoid using regular expressions whenever you can. They might get long, overly complicated, hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: Alright, understood. Are there any other module that can help besides requests_html?

Comment: @Blu you can also use `Selenium`, I updated my answer with a solution, however, I think this is an overkill if the only thing you want to achieve is getting the URLs and don't need to render the entire page to scrape any other data.

Answer (score 1):

> The HTML `<script>` element is used to embed or reference executable code; this is typically used to embed or refer to JavaScript code.

The page you scrape is rendered by JavaScript, the initial HTML contains a `<script>` tag with `images`  variable that contains URLs of all the pictures. You can either follow [Rakesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532312/rakesh) approach of extracting the JavaScript object containing URLs with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) or use [`Requests-HTML`](https://html.python-requests.org/) that uses Chromium under the hood to render the website as it appears in the browser.

You can get all the URLs with the code below:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://bato.to/chapter/1204541'
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()

urls = [img.attrs['src'] for img in r.html.find('.item > img')]
```

```
>>> urls
['https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/57a04a3ce55bd48debf0a486a4c1a48f6380ef9b_1066291_800_1138.png',
 'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/a0f75d10919430e6ef25a86c3dcc65f343d8e319_518773_800_1138.png',
 'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/575d00ff9ef6873ee9ecfb418e360fe72cc1c594_418309_800_1138.png',
 ...
]

>>> len(urls)
59
```

The issue of this solution is that it takes a long time to execute.

To clarify, `.item > img` targets all the `img` elements which are direct children of an element with `item` class.
You can read more about CSS selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

**You can also use [`Selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/):**

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
url_dict = browser.execute_script('return images;')
browser.quit()
```

```
>>> url_dict['1']
'https://file-comic-99.anyacg.co/uploads/5ae318893532c3405bd86baa/57a04a3ce55bd48debf0a486a4c1a48f6380ef9b_1066291_800_1138.png'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your answer. I never knew about the requests_html module. It seems that I have long way to learn. I'll use Rakesh's answer since I am familiar with regular expressions, but i'll be sure to check out the requests_html module doc to learn more about it.

Comment: I tried using the `request_html` method but I got trace back error saying:

`raise MaxRetries("Unable to render the page. Try increasing timeout")
requests_html.MaxRetries: Unable to render the page. Try increasing timeout`

Comment: @Blu try setting `timeout` keyword argument, e.g.: `r.html.render(timeout=20)` (the default is 8 seconds). To be honest it takes sooo long to render that it pretty much disqualifies this solution on this website. It takes 16 seconds to load even in my browser, so in this case, you should use the regex solution proposed by [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532312/rakesh) if you don't need any other data rendered by JS.

Comment: Its alright. I will use selenium method. I now have a reason to learn how to use it. Also, i think its better to avoid using regular expressions for html.